# Contact Form 7, extra fields doesn't get send

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following contact form but i only receive the standard fields in my email : name,subject,message 
Any ideas on how to solve this ?

```
<p>Name<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>email<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>subject<br />
[text your-subject] </p>

<p>Arrival Date <br/>
[date date-561 min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<p>Departure Date <br/>
[date date-561 min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of adults<br/>
[number* number-434 "2"]
</p>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of Children<br/>
[number* number-434 "0"]
</p>
</div>

<p>your message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>
[recaptcha]
</br>
<p>[submit "send"]</p>
```

Comment: Have you set up the fields to send in the message body within the 'Mail' tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use unique fields name,Please see below updated contact form.**

```
<p>Arrival Date <br/>
[date arrival-date min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<p>Departure Date <br/>
[date departure-date min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of adults<br/>
[number* adult-number "2"]
</p>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of Children<br/>
[number* children-number "0"]
</p>
```

**And in Message Body under tab "Mail" enter all your fields name like this**

```
Arrival Date: [arrival-date]
Departure Date: [departure-date]
Number of adults: [adult-number]
Number of Children: [children-number]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set-up your email from the ***Mail Tab***. The variables defined in the Form like: *date-561, number-434* need to be inserted on your Mail Tab. [Editor Screen Mail Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1C3F.png)

[Details Here: https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/)

Answer (score 2):

go to the mail tab in the contact form and add this codes to your message body:
Message Body:
Arrival Date: [date-561 ]
Departure Date : [date-562]
Number of Adults : [number-434]
Number of Children : [number-435]

change departure date code to [date-562] and Number of Children code to [number-435] in your main code

Answer (score 1):

Please use 
Unique name for your field in cf7

```
<p>Arrival Date <br/>
[date date-561 min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<p>Departure Date <br/>
[date date-561 min:2017-04-01 placeholder "01/04/2017"]
</p>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of adults<br/>
[number* number-434 "2"]
</p>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
<p>Number of Children<br/>
[number* number-434 "0"]
</p>
</div>
```

number 434 is 2 time same date varibale is also 2 times please check.